# Getting an error while using my application "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: generics, error-handling, infragistics

I have an application in which I am using an ultragrid whenever I am trying to write "8431", the application is getting an unhandled exception "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

[image: Screenshot of error]

I tried some online solution like running "sfc" command but there were no corrupted files in the system.
In other solution it is mentioned that this error occurs when we are trying to save any image, but I am not displaying any image or trying to save any image through my application.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Click the **_Details_** button and attach an additional information to your question. The red cross of failure is painted when a control's _OnPaint()_ method throws an exception.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, e.g., Visual Studio, then debug it like this, VS > Debug > Exceptions (run in debug mode / F5). Use call stack information to get exact line from where the exception has been raised.